# Why is my baked image black? What have I done wrong?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking

Why is my baked image black? What have I done wrong?

[image]
[image]

Link to the file: https://we.tl/t-ekBeME8dQq

Answer (score 2):

Your normals are flipped inside (red on screenshot), the baking rays go in the bad direction and don't hit any surface, so go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*:

[image]